# Finding an isomorphism of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

OK so basically the question asks me to find an explicit ring isomorphism 
$ \alpha: x^2+x+2 \mapsto x^2+2x+2$

Where both are under the field of five elements ie (0,1,2,3,4). I don't know how to get the F[5] symbol up, sorry.

So how do I find this?

I've got another example question which is to show that there is an isomorphism of fields

$x^2+2\cong x^2+x+2$

Again worded a bit differently but obviously asking the same thing and again over the field of five elements. Can someone guide me on how to do the first one so that I can do it myself on the second question and post here if it is correct? Thanks.

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind.

Comment: Is it standard to refer to polynomials as if they were fields? As I understand it, you want an isomorphism ${\bf F}_5[x]/(x^2+x+2)\cong{\bf F}_5[x]/(x^2+2x+2)$, right? The second is not a field, though, whereas the first is a field, so there is no isomorphism between them. The splitting fields are also non-isomorphic, if that's what you intended. Is there something I'm not seeing? Also, it appears your question *is* tagged as (abstract-algebra), like you wanted, right?

Comment: What "nevermind"? Your question or your comment?

Comment: The comment, most likely. When you say "nevermind" to a previous comment but then delete the comment you are referring to, you will tend to confuse others, OP.

Comment: To the OP, you can right click existing notational symbols here and bring up their TeX commands.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ X^2\!+\!2,\ x^2\!+\!x\!+\!2\ \:$ both have discriminant $\rm = -2 \in\Bbb F_5.\:$ Since $\rm\:-2\:$ isn't a square in $\,\Bbb F_5,\:$ and $\rm\:1/2 \in \Bbb F_5,\:$ we can use the quadratic formula to deduce that both extension fields are generated by adjoining $\rm\:\sqrt{-2}\:$ to $\,\Bbb F_5,\:$ i.e. $\rm\: R = \Bbb F_5[X]/(X^2\!+2)\, \cong\, \Bbb F_5[\sqrt{-2}]\,\cong\, \Bbb F_5[x]/(x^2\!+\!x\!+\!2) = R'.\:$ To construct an explicit isomorphism, use that, in $\rm\:R,\ \  X =\, \pm\sqrt{-2},\,$ and $\rm\:\pm\sqrt{-2}\,=\, 2x\!+\!1\,$ in $\rm\,R',\:$ since $\rm\:x=(-1\pm\sqrt{-2})/2\:$ by the quadratic formula (or, completing square $\rm\,\Rightarrow\, (2x\!+\!1)^2\! = -2),\:$ and use: $\rm\:h\,$ a ring hom and $\rm\:- 2 = X^2\Rightarrow\,-2 = h(X^2) = h(X)^2,\:$ i.e. $\rm\:h(\pm\sqrt{-2})\, =\, \pm\sqrt{-2}.$

If the first  is a typo for $\rm\:x^2\!+\!2x\!\color{#c00}{-\!2},\:$ with discriminant $\rm\:2,\:$ utilize $\rm\:X^2\!= -2\:\Rightarrow\,(2X)^2\! = 2\,$ in $\rm\,\Bbb F_5.$

Comment: Thanks for the solution but my mark scheme does it in a colmpletely different way?

Comment: @Lolwat Does it tell you how to discover the isomorphism, or does it simply pull it out of a hat, like magic? Above I try to give you some intuition about how to *discover* the correct isomorphism. If you post the solution in your answer then I can explain further.